# Accessing an object returned by a Mongo collection within render() method in .jsx file(React)

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, meteor

Assigning a variable `'res' = this.resolutions()` function within render() method

[image]

Output of initial code
In render() method, inside `<div> - {console.log(res[0])}` called once. But in the console, we can see it is executed thrice.

res is an object with an array of values (as it is referring to a Mongo collection with 8 documents)
[image]

Because the first execution of console.log(res[0]) is returning undefined, accessing the properties of the object i.e. {console.log(res[0].text} will throw an error

Comment: where the console.log is, call a method eg. {this.displayResolutions()} and then you can first check you have an array, then map the array to some output

Comment: Dear nithin raj, welcome to Stack Overflow, please, post your code in plain text format, as it makes it easier to understand and help you with. And explain your code outside the code blocks

Comment: I have edited your question, but please check the [tour] and the [ask] page!

Comment: @PeteGaulton , I am just understanding the flow of data i.e. retrieving data from a Mongo collection in Meteor. If I console.log outside the <div>, I get an empty array first. I am using the latest version of Meteor, could this be causing this behavior ?

Answer (score 1):

Everything here is working as intended. Do you understand what TrackerReact does and what it is for?

The three console outputs are very much expected, since TrackerReact's whole purpose is to re-render your component whenever the Meteor Data source changes. When the site loads initially, no data is available on the client side, and as the server sends the data you `Meteor.subscribe`'d to, TrackerReact will re-run `render()` so you can get the new data from `this.resolution()` via `.fetch()`.

For the same reason, it is very much expected for `this.resolution()` to return an empty array at any time. It is you Component's responsibility to deal with lack of data in a sensible way.

For example, if you are only interested in the first element, you should check for the length first:

```
if (res.length > 0) console.log(res[0]);
```

and if you want to display all of them you will most likely be using `Array.map`, which will be totally fine since it works on empty arrays too:

```
<div>
  {res.map(function (resolution) {
    return (<div>{resolution.text}</div>);
  })}
</div>
```